# EasyAdmin Collection Field: Button ID Conflict on Multiple Tabs

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

Multiple tabs and id conflicts on easy admin

Hello, I am setting up a backoffice with easy admin and I am facing a problem with the use of multiple tabs.

I have the following HouseholdCrudController which has 2 tabs, in the 2nd tab I have a CollectionField 'person' which uses a PersonCrudController.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Household;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Actions;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Assets;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ArrayField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ChoiceField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\CollectionField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FormField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TelephoneField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;

class HouseholdCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    const status = [
        'Marié' => 'Marié',
        'Pacsé' => 'Pacsé',
        'Concubinage' => 'Concubinage',
        'Célibataire' => 'Célibataire',
        'Veuf' => 'Veuf',
    ];

    const cssClass = 'col-md-6 col-xxl-6';

    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Household::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {

        yield FormField::addTab('Informations générales')
            ->collapsible()
            ->setIcon('fas fa-euro-sign')
            ->renderCollapsed();
        yield TextField::new('name', 'Foyer')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass);
        yield FormField::addRow();
        yield AssociationField::new('user', 'Utilisateur')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideOnForm();
        yield FormField::addRow();
            yield TelephoneField::new('cellPhone', 'Téléphone portable')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass);
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield TelephoneField::new('landlinePhone', 'Téléphone fixe')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->hideOnIndex();
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield ChoiceField::new('unionType', 'Type d\'union')
                ->setChoices(self::status)
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->hideOnIndex();
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield BooleanField::new('weddingContract', 'Contrat de mariage')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->hideOnIndex();
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield IntegerField::new('children', 'Nombre d\'enfants')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->hideOnIndex();
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield IntegerField::new('dependents', 'Dont à charge')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->hideOnIndex();
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield ArrayField::new('childrenAges', 'Ages des enfants')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/children_ages.html.twig')
                ->hideOnIndex();
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield IntegerField::new('taxUnits', 'Nombre de parts fiscales')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->hideOnIndex();
            yield FormField::addRow();
           yield ArrayField::new('DesiredMonthlySavings', 'Epargne mensuelle souhaitée')
               ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/desired_monthly_savings.html.twig')
               ->hideOnIndex();
            yield ArrayField::new('objectives', 'Objectifs')
                ->onlyOnDetail();
            yield FormField::addRow();
            yield AssociationField::new('objectives', 'Objectifs')
                ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
                ->onlyOnForms();
            yield DateField::new('createdAt', 'Date de création')
                ->hideOnForm();
            yield DateField::new('updatedAt', 'Date de modification')
                ->hideOnForm();

            yield FormField::addTab('Personnes')
                ->setFormTypeOption('block_name', 'person_') // Ajoutez cette ligne
                ->collapsible()
                ->setIcon('fas fa-users')
                ->renderCollapsed();
            yield CollectionField::new('persons', 'Personnes')
                ->allowAdd()
                ->allowDelete()
                ->useEntryCrudForm(PersonCrudController::class)
                ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/person.html.twig')
                ->setColumns(12);
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->disable(Action::DELETE)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, Action::INDEX)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, Action::DETAIL)
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::NEW, function (Action $action) {
                return $action->setLabel('Ajouter un foyer');
            })
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::EDIT, function (Action $action) {
                return $action->setIcon('fa fa-pencil');
            })
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DELETE, function (Action $action) {
                return $action->setIcon('fa fa-trash');
            })
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL, function (Action $action) {
                return $action->setIcon('fa fa-eye');
            });
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('foyers')
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('foyer')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, 'Liste des %entity_label_plural%')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_NEW, 'Ajouter un %entity_label_singular%')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, 'Modifier un %entity_label_singular%')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_DETAIL, 'Détail du %entity_label_singular%')
            ->setDateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
            ->setSearchFields(['name'])
            ->setDefaultSort(['createdAt' => 'DESC'])
            ->setFormThemes(['admin/form/custom_form_theme_panel.html.twig'])
            ->showEntityActionsInlined()
            ->renderContentMaximized();
    }

    public function configureAssets(Assets $assets): Assets
    {
        return $assets
            ->addWebpackEncoreEntry('admin')
            ->addJsFile('build/admin.js');

    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Person;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Actions;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ChoiceField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\CollectionField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\CountryField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FormField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;

class PersonCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    const STATUS = [
        'Salarié' => 'Salarié',
        'Libéral' => 'Libéral',
    ];

    const cssClass = 'col-md-6 col-xxl-6';

    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Person::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        yield FormField::addTab('Etat civil')
            ->collapsible()
            ->setIcon('fas fa-user')
            ->renderCollapsed();

        yield TextField::new('firstName', 'Prénom')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass);

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield TextField::new('lastName', 'Nom')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass);

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield AssociationField::new('household', 'Foyer')
            ->formatValue(function ($value, $entity) {
                return $entity?->getHousehold()?->getName();
            })
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideWhenUpdating();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield DateField::new('birthDate', 'Date de naissance')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield TextField::new('birthPlace', 'Lieu de naissance')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield CountryField::new('nationality', 'Nationalité')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield ChoiceField::new('status', 'Statut')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->setChoices(self::STATUS)
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield TextField::new('occupation', 'Profession')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield TextField::new('employer', 'Employeur')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield IntegerField::new('seniority', 'Ancienneté')
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield DateField::new('createdAt', 'Date de création')
            ->hideOnForm();

        yield DateField::new('updatedAt', 'Date de modification')
            ->hideOnForm();

        yield FormField::addTab('Revenus')
            ->collapsible()
            ->setIcon('fas fa-euro-sign')
            ->renderCollapsed();

        yield AssociationField::new('income', 'Revenus')
            ->renderAsEmbeddedForm()
            ->setCrudController(IncomeCrudController::class)
            ->setColumns(self::cssClass)
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/income.html.twig')
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield FormField::addTab('Charges')
            ->collapsible()
            ->setIcon('fas fa-euro-sign')
            ->renderCollapsed();

        yield CollectionField::new('loads', 'Charges')
            ->useEntryCrudForm(LoadCrudController::class)
            ->setColumns(12)
            ->setLabel(false)
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/load.html.twig')
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addRow();

        yield FormField::addTab('Épargnes')
            ->collapsible()
            ->setIcon('fas fa-euro-sign')
            ->renderCollapsed();

        yield CollectionField::new('savings', 'Épargnes')
            ->useEntryCrudForm(SavingCrudController::class)
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
            ->setColumns(12)
            ->setLabel(false)
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/saving.html.twig')
            ->hideOnIndex();

        yield FormField::addTab('Immobilier')
            ->collapsible()
            ->setIcon('fas fa-home')
            ->renderCollapsed();

        yield CollectionField::new('assets', 'Biens immobiliers')
            ->useEntryCrudForm(AssetCrudController::class)
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
            ->setColumns(12)
            ->setLabel(false)
            ->hideOnIndex();
    }


    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->disable(Action::DELETE)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, Action::INDEX)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, Action::DETAIL)->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::NEW, function (Action $action) {
                return $action->setLabel('Ajouter une personne');
            })
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::EDIT, function (Action $action) {
                return $action->setIcon('fa fa-pencil');
            })
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL, function (Action $action) {
                return $action->setIcon('fa fa-eye');
            });
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('personnes')
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('personne')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, 'Liste des %entity_label_plural%')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_NEW, 'Ajouter une %entity_label_singular%')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, 'Modifier une %entity_label_singular%')
            ->setPageTitle(Crud::PAGE_DETAIL, 'Détail de la %entity_label_singular%')
            ->setDateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
            ->setSearchFields(['firstName', 'lastName', 'household.name'])
            ->setDefaultSort(['createdAt' => 'DESC'])
            ->showEntityActionsInlined()
            ->renderContentMaximized();
    }
}
```

In this PersonCrudController I have multiple tabs also, which use respectively other CrudControllers associated to their entities.

The code works, I have the desired interface however I have a problem at the frontend, when I try to create or edit a 'person' from the HouseholdController I notice that in the CollectionField the buttons of the 2nd element that allows access to the different nested forms have the same ID attributes as those of the first element this causes a bug that prevents to switch to the different forms of the second element when creating or editing, in fact when we look in the DOM we see that the tabs have the same ID attributes.

I tried to add a custom theme form but couldn't get it right. I tried to make an event subscriber with the AfterCrudActionEvent, I took to find the IDs that are used in the DOM but I did not manage to get them and modify them.

Thanks in advance for your help